# Mocking angular js service call in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have Controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {

        // Start -----> Service call: Get Initial Data
        myService.getInitialData().getData(function (featureManagerdata) {
            var serviceData = featureManagerdata;
        }, function (error) {
            showErrorMessage(error, 'getinitialdata');                
        });
    });
}());
```

Here is my service: Using $resource making call on getInitialData with getData as custom function.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', ['$resource', myService]);

    function myService($resource) {
        var hostUrl = 'http://x.x.x.x/WebAPIDev';

        function getInitialData() {
            var url = hostUrl + '/featuremanager/allfeatures';
            var options = {
                getData: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true
                }
            };
            return $resource(url, {}, options);
        );

        return {
            getInitialData: getInitialData
        };
    }
}());
```

Wanted to test service call in controller using karma-jasmine:

TestMyCtrl:

```
describe('Test my controller', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var scope, Ctrl, service;

    angular.module('myApp').service('mockService', function($resource) {
        getInitialData = function() {
            return {
                'featureId': 1
            };
        }
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, mockService) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        Ctrl = _$controller_('myCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            service: mockService
        });
    }));

    it('should test get initial data', function() {
        var response, mockUserResource, $httpBackend, result;

        service.getInitialData().getData(function(data) {
            response = data;
            // verify data
        });
    });
});
```

This throws error, service.getInitialData is not function. Any idea why it is throwing error or any other better way to test service call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, there are some differences between `factory` and `service`, check [Service vs Factory vs Provider in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory) if you want to know more about it.

One of them is **factory** return reference **Object** and service return an **Instance**

So when you try to define/mock a function or property in factory, you return an `Object` with property name and value, but **in service, you should set it to `this`**.

And beyond of that, you should return a Object which define a function `getData` so that it can be invoked in your last test case.(Or it will throw **undefine is not a function**  error)

So update your `TestMyCtrl` into this,

```
describe('Test my controller', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var scope, Ctrl, service;

    angular.module('myApp').service('mockService', function($resource) {
        //set the function to this.
        this.getInitialData = function() {
            //return {
            //    'featureId': 1
            //};
            //return an object which defined getData function.

            return {
                getData: function(func) {
                    var data = {
                        featureId: 1
                    };
                    //do something here if you want.
                    func(data);
                }
            };
        }
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, mockService) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        Ctrl = _$controller_('myCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            service: mockService
        });
    }));

    it('should test get initial data', function() {
        var response, mockUserResource, $httpBackend, result;

        service.getInitialData().getData(function(data) {
            response = data;
            // verify data
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this can answer your question. : )